# Unable to load Windows in grub

Tags: grub2, bios

I have Ubuntu installed alongside Windows8.1. Grub has the menu item for windows but if I recall correctly I only get message saying it is unable to mount the drive.

I know the windows partition is working correctly and CAN get into it if I catch bios and change what it boots into.

<s>I'm OK with not being able to use grub if its not possible, but I wanted to know of there is anyway to change the boot order in bios to boot into windows on boot rather than Ubuntu if for any reason I want to use windows as the primary for a while.</s>

I need to know how to add windows to the grub menu where it will fix the list item to actually boot into windows when chosen

Sorry for run ons or incorrect spelling, I am somewhat in a hurry and on my phone.

Comment: We only support Ubuntu and official derivaties. EOS and Windows neither are.

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases so Elementary OS is off-topic here as well. However, on http://unix.stackexchange.com, a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at all varieties of Linux and Unix, so you might be better off there.  ;-)

Comment: But elementary OS is pretty much just a re-themed Ubuntu from what I understood. Also Windows and Ubuntu is done side by side frequently it's hard to believe you wouldn't answer a question simply because someone is asking how to better make them work together.

Comment: Instead of lying, post on the correct site: [unix.se].

Comment: I'm not lying, Elementary IS Ubuntu, any solution to this question that works for Ubuntu WILL work on elementary, and vice-versa. I'm not going to remove a question that could help someone else in the future simply because the operating system has a name and theme difference. And even if they weren't, this question does not pertain to the Operating system specifically, it pertains to an issue with the Grub2 Boot loader which comes with both operating systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I have only used this fix on Windows 8.1, I have no way of knowing if it will work the same on other versions of windows***

I have found the answer myself and although Elementary (an Ubuntu based OS) seems to be oddly frowned upon topic here, this should also work on regular Ubuntu systems as well.

My goal was to either get Grub to be able to boot into windows through it's menu list, OR change the boot order of BIOS to boot windows as the primary OS rather then elementary when needed (The BIOS one understandably not a topic to be answered). And I had found the solution to the GRUB2 issue.

What happened was from my understanding secure boot was turned on and was doing it's job, preventing things from accessing and/or installing unwanted programs onto the drive. Simply turning off secure boot did not fix everything completely but it did allow grub to access the other partition. Here are the steps:

1. Restart your computer and boot into the BIOS settings *(In my case it was done by pressing F12 on Dell)*
2. Find the boot options, they should be near the bottom
3. I'm sure the option might differ but in my case I chose to turn off secure boot with UEFI turned on, It worked for me but I have heard *using Legacy over UEFI works best on Ubuntu systems.*

**IF YOUR COMPUTER BOOTS INTO THE WINDOWS PARTITION AFTER THE RESTART**

4. Boot into BIOS the same way you did in the first step.
5. Boot into the Ubuntu (or elementary) partition under the UEFI list.
6. Download, install and run Boot-Repair inside of a terminal window [Installing boot repair- via help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
   ```
7. Run boot-repair using the recommended settings button. This will reinstall Grub2 and change the boot order in the BIOS to boot to the partition GRUB has been installed to.
8. Save the link at the end of the process in case you have issues.
9. Restart your computer.
10. Windows should be in the Grub list, and when selected will boot you into windows.

--

Now that you can boot into windows using grub you can change the grub boot order to have the windows partition selected by default in the timeout rather than Ubuntu.